# matching dataset with data in csv file in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

Suppose i have data

```
mydat=structure(list(id = 1:6, x2 = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), 
    x3 = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L)), .Names = c("id", "x2", 
"x3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Also i have file csv

```
test=read.csv(path,sep=";", dec",")
```

it has this stucture

```
test=structure(list(id = 1:5, x2 = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), x3 = c(12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L)), .Names = c("id", "x2", "x3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

How can i match these 2 datasets in such  way that from `mydat` were  removed
observations which have similar id with `test`?

I.E. output must be

```
id  x2  x3
6   12  12
```

cause `id 1,2,3,4,5` in `mydat` is similar with `test` dataset.

Comment: Or if you're not a tidyverse fan, you can use `merge(..., all=T)` and then drop the rows where the merge was successful.

Comment: @DanY how exactly do you drop the rows? That is OP question

Comment: Here's a better comment:  `mydat[!(mydat$id %in% test$id), ]`  Thanks for keeping me honest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `anti_join` from dplyr`

```
 dplyr::anti_join(mydat,test)
Joining, by = c("id", "x2", "x3")
  id x2 x3
1  6 12 12
```

In base R: you can collapse down the data into strings and compare them:

```
mydat[!do.call(paste,mydat)%in%do.call(paste,test),]
  id x2 x3
6  6 12 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Using R base.

```
> mydat[setdiff(mydat$id, test$id), ]
  id x2 x3
6  6 12 12
```